Applying french characters/formatting in ggplot axis labels
I am struggling to generate timeseries plots using ggplot2 library in both english and french. I am using the setlocale() to correctly portray months in French, but I am struggling to generate y-axis labels correctly using expression().
For example, the french translation of river discharge (flow) is "Débit". When I run the following sample code, the generated plot garbles the e (with accent aigu) producing "DÄ©bit".
n <- 365
data <- data.frame(
  Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2024-01-01"), length.out = n, by = "days"),
  Value = rnorm(n)
)

# adjust local settings to show in French
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "French")

# french translation for Discharge (m3/s)
y_label <- expression("Débit " ~ (m^3/s))

ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(Date, Value)) + 
  ylab(y_label)

# set settings back to default English
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")

here is my session info:
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
system code page: 65001

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.9.2   ggplot2_3.4.1     dplyr_1.1.0       tidyr_1.3.0       tidyWOffice_0.1.0 tidyhydat_0.5.9   readxl_1.4.2     
[8] here_1.0.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr2_0.2.2       cellranger_1.1.0  pillar_1.9.0      compiler_4.2.2    dbplyr_2.3.1      tools_4.2.2       bit_4.0.5        
 [8] timechange_0.2.0  RSQLite_2.3.1     memoise_2.0.1     lifecycle_1.0.3   tibble_3.1.8      gtable_0.3.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[15] rlang_1.1.3       cli_3.6.0         DBI_1.1.3         rstudioapi_0.14   parallel_4.2.2    curl_5.0.0        fastmap_1.1.1    
[22] stringr_1.5.0     withr_2.5.0       systemfonts_1.0.4 hms_1.1.2         generics_0.1.3    vctrs_0.5.2       rappdirs_0.3.3   
[29] rprojroot_2.0.3   bit64_4.0.5       grid_4.2.2        tidyselect_1.2.0  glue_1.6.2        R6_2.5.1          textshaping_0.3.6
[36] fansi_1.0.4       vroom_1.6.1       farver_2.1.1      tzdb_0.3.0        readr_2.1.4       purrr_1.0.1       blob_1.2.4       
[43] magrittr_2.0.3    ellipsis_0.3.2    scales_1.2.1      colorspace_2.1-0  ragg_1.2.5        labeling_0.4.2    utf8_1.2.3       
[50] stringi_1.7.12    munsell_0.5.0     cachem_1.0.7      crayon_1.5.2     

Thanks in advance!

Did you make sure your editor uses UTF-8 encoding (see here for RStudio)?

By default Sys.setlocale(locale="French") will use code page 1252 on Windows which is not utf8 (your session info state that the system is using code page 65001 which is utf8 on Windows). Try to set Sys.setlocale("French.utf8") instead. And yes also make sure rstudio is set to use utf8 by default.

@Billy34 That worked perfectly! Thanks for the help.
